# How to setup karma and jasmine to write unit tests for angular4 app?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I want to setup karma and jasmine for my angular4 app.
For that I had followed the steps in this link.

https://medium.com/developing-an-angular-4-web-app/setting-up-unit-tests-for-our-angular-4-app-2ad6e165f1f6

After following the steps accordingly, I am getting this error on console

```
08 05 2018 11:39:52.635:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
08 05 2018 11:39:52.650:INFO [karma]: Karma v2.0.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
08 05 2018 11:41:09.271:INFO [Chrome 66.0.3359 (Windows 10.0.0)]: Connected on socket iyXlcgEjYBd-Lol7AAAA with id manual-3812
Chrome 66.0.3359 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "message": "You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!",
    "str": "You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!"
  }
```

I executed the command 'karma start'.

Comment: what is the version of angular that you are using?

Comment: Please add some comments as well to let me know whats wrong with the question before downvoting...It will be helpful for me :)

Comment: Its angular4....

Comment: I f you have create your angular application with angular-cli. Jasmine and karma is already configured for you.. You have to write unit tests and run `ng test` command.

Comment: yes its in angular cli, but karma and jasmine were not configured.

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of the following reasons.

> 1. If you try to do karma start in a different folder location.
> 2. If you did not restart it after changing your configuration.

Please ensure the above two and hopefully it will work.

Comment: I think your first point is valid as when I try to run the above command from the folder in which my karma.conf.js resides, I don't get this error. But now I am getting a bunch of different errors.